# Dynamic defualt filter for a HTML table with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

I am managing a large CSV file with columns that show the date, time and message.

Currently I have managed to convert my large CSV file into a HTML table with some additional Javascript code. I have also managed to put in a filter so I can filter out specific words, dates and times.

Now I am currently stuck with setting a dynamic default value. Basically the (hidden) filter should only display rows with the current Month and Day. This way I can look back at messages that were send X years ago on this date.

Like mentioned my current filter is an input field and definitly not the automatic way like I want to

I am also not ready to use anything other than Javascript. My knowledge beyond HTML and CSS doesnt go that far

HTML: for simplicity a table is structured here.
Note that the date-data is marked as MM/DD/YY.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="myInput" 
  onkeyup="myFunction()" 
  placeholder="Search for names or countries.." 
  title="Type in a name or a country">

<table>
<tr>
<td> 12/20/19</td>
<td> 01:39  </td>
<td> Rens: Wat </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 12/20/20</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rocco Haagenhuizen: In de chat </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 12/19/21</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rens: Wacht </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 12/20/21</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rocco Haagenhuizen: Ga naar je chats </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript: input filter

```
const myFunction = () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('Table tr')
  const filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i')
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(td.innerHTML)
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds)
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({ style, children }) => {
    style.display = isFound([
      ...children // <-- All columns
    ]) ? '' : 'none' 
  }
  
  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bxwvqo7/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  const trs = document.querySelectorAll('Table tr')
  const filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value
  const regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i')
  const isFoundInTds = td => regex.test(td.innerHTML);
  const now = new Date();
  const isRightDate = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(td => {
    const tdDate = new Date(td.innerHTML);
    return tdDate.getDate() === now.getDate()
        && tdDate.getMonth() === now.getMonth();
  });
  const isFound = childrenArr => childrenArr.some(isFoundInTds)
  const setTrStyleDisplay = ({ style, children }) => {
    style.display = isRightDate([...children])
      && isFound([
        ...children // <-- All columns
      ]) ? '' : 'none';
  }
  
  trs.forEach(setTrStyleDisplay)
}
myFunction();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  width: 209px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="myInput" 
  onkeyup="myFunction()" 
  placeholder="Search for names or countries.." 
  title="Type in a name or a country">

<table>
<tr>
<td> 12/13/19</td>
<td> 01:39  </td>
<td> Rens: Wat </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 12/14/20</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rocco Haagenhuizen: In de chat </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 12/13/21</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rens: Wacht </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 2/13/21</td>
<td> 01:40  </td>
<td> Rocco Haagenhuizen: Ga naar je chats </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```